# socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, gsutil

I am trying to install gsutil on my windows 7 machine. I am following the instructions from here -> https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install

but I am getting the following error when I run the 4th step(python gsutil):

socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

maybe some proxy issues?

Thanks in advance.